# Checking textFields for entered characters

Tags: ios, nsstring, textview, uitextfield, character

I use the function to check that character user is typed.
And it works.
Problem is if user make copy-paste and the text contains some restricted characters - the text not appears.

I launch it from  shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

How can I override this function to return string that contains all allowed characters, but not restricted?

```
 + (BOOL)isValidCharacters:(NSDictionary *)parameters forString:(NSString *)string
{
//выбираем разрешенные символы
NSMutableCharacterSet *allowedCharacters = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc]init];

if (parameters[@"whitespaceCharacterSet"])//пробел
[allowedCharacters formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

if (parameters[@"decimalDigitCharacterSet"]) //цифры
    [allowedCharacters formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];

if (parameters[@"alphanumericCharacterSet"]) //буквы цифры
[allowedCharacters formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];

if (parameters[@"symbolCharacterSet"]) //символы
[allowedCharacters formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];

if (parameters[@"letterCharacterSet"])//буквы
    [allowedCharacters formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];

if (parameters[@"arbitraryCharacters"]) //набор
[allowedCharacters addCharactersInString:@":.,;_!()/\n"];

if (parameters[@"email"]) //email
    [allowedCharacters addCharactersInString:@"._@"];

if([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:allowedCharacters.invertedSet].location == NSNotFound)
{

    return YES;
}

return NO;
```

Comment: Change this method to return the "filtered" string.

Comment: How can I create this string/?